# ¿Cómo acceder a mi base de datos mysql en mi hosting?

Tags: mysql, android, webservice, godaddy

Sucede que estoy estudiando la conexión de base de datos remota en Android usando Volley. Yo tengo una base de datos en mi hosting de godaddy. Cuando creo la base de datos por lógica debo crear un usuario y una contraseña para acceder a mi base de datos. Por lo tanto yo creo mi usuario y mi contraseña. Ahora bien, el archivo webService.php que es donde tengo la conexión a la base de datos y las consultas hago un deploy en el dominio que tengo y efectivamente al acceder a ese dominio se ve que el archivo funciona porque hago una validación que en caso que n se envien parámetros de tipo GET retorne un array con el mesnaje de error y otros campos. sin embargo, cuando si le envío parámetros como a continuación:

```html
 if (isset($_GET['id'])){
 
    try {
           
      $id=$_GET['id'];

      $conexion=connection();

      $sql="SELECT id,fullName,profession FROM user WHERE id ={$id}";
      $result=$conexion->query($sql);

      if($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $json['user'][]=$row;
      }
      else{
          $result=array(
            'status'=>'Error',
            'id'=>0,
            'name'=>'No registrado',
            'profession'=>'No registrado'
          );
            $json=$result;
      }

      echo json_encode($json, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

      } catch (\Exception $e) {
          echo "No se puede conectar a la base de datos";
      }

    }else{
        $result=array(
            'status'=>'Error',
            'id'=>0,
            'name'=>'No retorna',
            'profession'=>'No retorna'
        );

        echo json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    }
```

Como mencioné anteriormente, este archivo lo estoy subiendo al dominio y está funcionando. No obstante, al parecer el dominio se conecta con el usuario por defecto que da el hosting, el cual es un nombre raro.
Total que cuando quiero conectarme de manera remota a mi base de datos mysql de cpanel me sale este error.

```
Access denied for user 'iijpiev5dhmx'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Efectivamente le niega el permiso a ese usuario porque no es user de la base de datos. Ese usuario es el que usa mi dominio. Ese mismo usuario quise crearlo en la base de datos pero no me permite y no veo manera que el dominio tome el mismo usuario de mi base de datos. También ya revisé que tengo bien las credenciales en mi función de conexión. Bueno ese es mi problema.

Comment: En el script PHP puedes conectarte al usuario que ya existe (el que GoDaddy te asignó cuando abriste la cuenta y se creó la base de datos). ¿Por qué quieres conectar con otro usuario distinto?

Comment: yo haria lo siguiente. Primero: testea el usuario (no imprescindible en este punto pero te evitas sorpresas mas adelante). 2.- Debugging, a ver de donde se saca el usuario y la contrasena viejos. 3.- borra caches de todas partes

Comment: por cierto, no veo donde metes los parametros de conexion

Comment: eso está en una  función connection.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando tienes un hostig en **GoDaddy** este mismo te asigna un nombre de usuario, por lo que si desas acceder a tu base de datos seria algo como esto:

A tu conexion le pasas los siguientes parametros:

- Server: localhost
- Usuario: el usuario que te asigna **GoDaddy**
- Contraseña: la misma que utilizas para entrar al Cpanel
- Base de datos: La que has creado.

En **GoDaddy** en la lista de tus productos tendras **Web Hosting** das click en administrar, veras una tabla con informacion de tu hosting, como el usuario de cpanel y la contraseña.

Comment: Ya introduje el usuario que aparece en la captura de arriba con la contraseña que entro pero sale igual.